# Extrair apenas números de uma lista

Tags: r, api, lista

Estou usando o pacote no R `fbRads` para coletar dados de Facebook Ads. Porém, quando transformo ele num data frame, recebo uma lista com os valores, ao invés do valor numérico. Como consigo separar só este valor?

```
library(fbRads)
library(tidyr)
library(jsonlite)
library(googlesheets)
library(stringr)
auth = fbad_init("", "", version='3.0')
Facebook = fb_insights(auth, time_increment="1", level="ad", fields =         
toJSON(c("impressions", "date_start", "ad_name", "adset_name", 
"campaign_name", "clicks", "spend", "inline_post_engagement", 
"video_10_sec_watched_actions","video_avg_percent_watched_actions", 
"video_p95_watched_actions", "actions", "link_click")))
Facebook = as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, Facebook))
data.frame(t(sapply(Facebook,c)))
```

Recebo essa lista de outputs como resposta. Preciso que cada um desses seja uma coluna separada no dataframe padrão.

[image]

Comment: Lucas, edite sua pergunta com o texto em português. E, se possível, disponibilize a parte do seu código que você está utilizando para facilitar nas respostas.

Comment: Coloque um exemplo da saída obtida e a saída esperada, isso pode ajudar as pessoas a responderem.

Comment: Não ponha imagens, copie a saída e poste essa saída como texto, por favor.

Comment: busque pelas funções `unnest` e `spread` do pacote `tidyr`. Suas chances de obterem uma resposta melhor aumentariam bastante se você colocar pelo menos um pedaço desse objeto `Facebook`. Você pode, por exemplo, no final da pergunta colocar o resultado de `dput(head(Facebook))`.